# Trying to optimize reading a very large SQLite database

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a very large SQLite file that I would like to read in Python (3.9.2), as fast as possible.
On each row I have to do some operations (involving external parameters outside the database so I cannot use the SQLite create_function), so I have to read simply row by row.
It seems that most of the time is spent in the reading loop.

As a reference, we can consider this dummy SQLite database generator create.py:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse, contextlib, sqlite3, timeit

def create_file(rows, columns, output):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    with contextlib.closing(sqlite3.connect(output)) as connection, connection, contextlib.closing(connection.cursor()) as cursor:
        headers = ','.join('[headers{}] text'.format(i) for i in range(columns))
        cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE [output] ({})'.format(headers))
        fields = ','.join('?' for i in range(columns))
        statement = 'INSERT INTO output VALUES ({})'.format(fields)
        dummy_row = ["0000000000000000"] * columns
        for i in range(rows):
            cursor.execute(statement, dummy_row)
    end = timeit.default_timer()
    print("Executed in: {}".format(end-start))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('generate dummy file')
    parser.add_argument("columns", type=int, help="number of columns")
    parser.add_argument("rows", type=int, help="number of rows")
    parser.add_argument('output', help='output file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    create_file(args.rows, args.columns, args.output)
```

We can generate a 10GB file with the command:

```
python create.py 50 10000000 dummy.sqlite
Executed in: 81.07768724599737
```

And we can read it with the SQLite file reader.py:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse, sqlite3, contextlib, timeit

def read_file(input):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    with contextlib.closing(sqlite3.connect(input)) as connection, connection, contextlib.closing(connection.cursor()) as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * from output")
        for row in cursor:
            pass
    end = timeit.default_timer()
    print("Executed in: {}".format(end-start))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('read file')
    parser.add_argument('input', help='input file')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    read_file(args.input)
```

Result is:

```
python3 read.py dummy.sqlite
Executed in: 89.3538507129997
```

I have tried playing with PRAGMA, reading in batches (fetchmany or SELECT/LIMIT), generating indexes but I haven't been able to have significant results (at most winning 2-3 seconds).

As a reference, my system can copy the file quite quickly:

```
cp dummy.sqlite dummy_copy.sqlite

real 0m18,464s
user 0m0,070s
sys  0m12,175s
```

Am I simply reaching the physical limit of python+sqlite3 library and the only way to go faster would be to change the code language ? Or is there any tricks that someone can recommend ?

Comment: A copy simply reads all the bytes off of the file system, as fast as possible and writes them somewhere else without paying any attention to their value or meaning. Reading a SQL database with queries requires far more logic and processing and won't even get close to the speed of a straight-up copy. What problem are you really trying to solve here? Once the data is in memory, what do you plan to do with it?

Comment: The copy command was only there to provide some reference for the absolute lowest possible time (i.e impossible to go below around 9 seconds; as copy involves reading+writing). For each row, I have to perform some operations on the row values (quite complex operation involving outside resources and update of another database, so I cannot use the trick with create_function). However after profiling, most of the time is spent in the loop itself and not in the complex operation, so I want to optimize that part if possible.